# Converting a foreach loop to a Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#

I am having trouble converting a `foreach` loop to a `Task.WhenAll`.

The method returns a `Task<byte[]>`

```
foreach (var p in ps)
{
    p.reportDownload = await runReport(p);
}
```

I have tried this but it needs the await to convert the `Task<byte[]>` to a `byte[]` and I can't add it.

```
await Task.WhenAll(ps.Select(p => p.reportDownload = runReport(p)));
```

I am attempting to download about 15 reports async to wait for all of them to have been downloaded before consolidating them into one pdf.

**NOTE:** I am using Framework 4.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
await Task.WhenAll(ps.Select(async p => p.reportDownload = await runReport(p)));
```

Comment: I was so close! Thanks